# Cannot set break points on chrome dev tool

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am wondering why the breakpoints cannot be set on some lines such as 969 and 972. It's in a i frame. Is this the reason?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm confusing, I can when using the same logic.
It would be great if you could post it in a Js bucket.

Side note:
Another method for setting breakpoints is using the "debugger" statement.
after a line.

e.g.

```
console.log("hello")
debugger
console.log("after debugger")
```